# YouTube iframe player API - OnStateChange 0 not firing

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api

As title states,

I am implementing a video via youtube iframe API, wanting to fire an event once video ends.

I can get player events for "playing" and "pausing" (1,2),
but not for video ended (0).
I always get "an error occured" message in the youtube player.

Adding the jsfiddle's as comment...

Any help is welcome, thanks!

**EDIT:**

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle[.]net/nSpDM/14/

**NOTE:** FF did not fire because of this Greasemonkey script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002

Comment: What I tried based on all stackoverflow results:  
http://jsfiddle.net/nSpDM/10/  
http://jsfiddle.net/anbUw/1/  
http://jsfiddle.net/wxYyy/

Comment: I tried the latest one: http://jsfiddle.net/wxYyy/ ; And it shows 4 alert boxes:  1, 2, 0, drama. The video plays and stop at the end. Does not show any error message at all.

Comment: i used Chrome. On Firfox it also seems to work, but i get 12 alert boxes with the values: 3, -1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, drama and 2.The video plays and ends.

Comment: @Als: I always get an error message, see here: http://imgur.com/4Kw6lKE  -  do you have an idea why is that? Also, in FF nothing alerts for me at all! I have the latest FF and Chrome.

Comment: NO, but I have seen such an error before, like yesterday. This happened in a list of several videos, which are all triggerd in the same way. While this type of error occurred on a video, it did not on other videos in that list. Try some other videos. I have not looked at the cause of this error yet. I suppose such a video may have a different status or different available type (mp4,webm). Also check your version of installed Flash Player. Have you tried with a bigger size (height and width) ?

Comment: I am using FF version 23.0.1

Comment: Forget about changing the size. I just tried again my list of videos: to play that video that gave me the same error you have. But it plays now! I'm quit sure i did not change anything. (But my computer was started again after shutdown at night.) BTW, i am using Flash Player version 11.8.800.94.

Comment: @Als: I think the video I used in the jsfiddles was too short somehow. -  http://jsfiddle.net/nSpDM/14/ - This works for me just fine now with Chrome 29.0.1547.62 m - In FF 23.0.1 I get errors thrown in Firebug, see this picture: http://imgur.com/masZPXY - No alerts in FF are popping up...

Comment: It seems to me, that these error(s) are from the inserted youtube-api-player code of YouTube and if so should be ignored, since you can't change that; but maybe reported as a bug. In FF i was using html5 video, not flash-player. But i changed it to Flash Player now  and it still works fine: the alert boxes do pop-up in FF. It seems flash-player is different per browser. I have Chrome 29.0.1547.62m and FP 11.8.800.115. And FF 23.0.1 and FP 11.8.800.94.

Comment: Have you tried a different O.S. (XP,W7,W8, etc.) ? Maybe it is different javascript behavior ?

Comment: @Als: Can confirm the differences in the Flash Player Versions, I got the same. - I still wonder though that you get alerts in FF. For me nothing happens. Usually if Firebug displays JS errors, it stops executing those JS, so the alerts would not pop-up?

Comment: @Als: I am on Vista SP2 32Bit. - Got no other OS at Hand...

Comment: @Als: IE9 + Opera12 + Safari 5 it's also working, just FF :(

Comment: Maybe its a FF setting, that you can set, to continue the script after any error ?

Comment: @Als: I thought something like that, but then I remembered I had a Greasemonkey Script for Youtube http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002  -  disabling this script solves the issue. Totally my fault for not thinking of this in the first place! - Thank you for all your valuable input!